# How to write and read files in browser JS like vscode.dev

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I want to read & write files with the user permission. [Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciL6u.png)
[And Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPD5y.png)

I tried FileHandlerApi and a lot of things.

Just i want to make something like that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File permission web</title>
    <script>
      const reqPerm = () => {
        // Code to request permission ( Write and Read )
      };

      const createFile = (fileName) => {
        // Code to create File
      };

      const deleteFile = (path) => {
        // Code to delete file
      };

      const editFile = (path, content) => {
        // Code to edit file
      };

      const viewFile = (path) => {
        // Code to view file
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>File permission</h1>
      </br>
      <button onclick="reqPerm()">Get permission</button>
      </br>
      <button onclick="createFile('hello.txt')">Create file</button>
      </br>
      <button onclick="deleteFile('/home/runner/renne/hello.txt')">Delete file</button>
      </br>
      <button onclick="editFile('/home/runner/renne/hello.txt', 'hellomg')">Edit File</button>
      </br>
      <button onclick="viewFile('/home/runner/renne/hello.txt')">View file</button>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that idk how to request permission so is there any api or any way?
I think is possible because vscode.dev can make it on chromebook, windows, linux, etc..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle

Comment: @Teemu How to request permission?

Comment: Mind to read the linked MDN article and follow links ...